# adding certificate to windows store using chef windows cookbook

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, pfx

I am using "windows" cookbook available in chef super market, when I use "windows_certificate" resource I get below error

```
STDOUT:
STDERR: C:\Users\pratikg\AppData\Local\Temp\chef-script20160712-8616-xwbm5w.ps1 : Exception calling ".ctor" with "3"
argument(s): "Cannot find the requested object.
"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,chef-script20160712-8616-xwbm5w.ps1
---- End output of "C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Execu
tionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None -File "C:/Users/pratikg/AppData/Local/Temp/chef-script20160712-8616-xwbm5w.ps1" ----

Ran "C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypa
ss -InputFormat None -File "C:/Users/pratikg/AppData/Local/Temp/chef-script20160712-8616-xwbm5w.ps1" returned 1
```

I have added below code to my cookbook

```
windows_certificate "c:/temp/cert.pfx" do     
    pfx_password    "password"   
end
```

Below are version details

```
Cookbook version - 1.44.1
Chef-client version - 12.11.18
Platform Details - Windows 7 64bit & 2012 R2 64bit
Powershell version - 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the file `c:/temp/cert.pfx` earlier in your recipe? You may also need to supply the `store_name` to tell Chef where to actually put the certificate if it doesn't default to a certain certificate store. There is also a note in the `chef-cookbooks/windows` recipe about installing certificates to the user store not always working over WinRM due to some limitations.